# Creating shapes with Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

If I have a few lists of lists that create grids which contain '#',' ','X' and 'O' how could I go about using the Tkinter library to represent these as different coloured squares on a canvas?

I am able to do it statically for one of the lists, but am unsure of how to make it dynamic so that I can load in each list.

This is the canvas that I wish to create it on:

```
self._canvas = Canvas(root, relief=SUNKEN, bg="black", width=300, height=300)
self._canvas.pack(side=TOP, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what your problem is, but you could just iterate over your grid like this:

```
DICT_COLOR = {'#':'red', 'X':'green', 'O':'yellow'}
SIZE_X = 300/len(grid[0])
SIZE_Y = 300/len(grid)
for i, line in enumerate(grid):
    for j, value in enumerate(line):
        self._canvas.create_rectangle(j*SIZE_X,
                                      i*SIZE_Y, 
                                      (j+1)*SIZE_X, 
                                      (i+1)*SIZE_Y, 
                                      fill=DICT_COLOR[value])
```

Comment: I am trying to open up a text file containing those characters, convert them to a list of lists such as [['#','#'],['X','#'],[' ','O']] and display that as a grid on a canvas.

Comment: So your problem is how to get the list of lists from the text file? If so, could you provide an example of such a file?

Comment: My problem is how to get the list of lists presented on to the canvas. I am having trouble, as the canvas is defined in one class(gui), and the list in the other.